# Unhelpful error message in g++

Tags: g++

I get these errors messages all over the place for g++ 4.1.2, and it doesn't help at all:

```
<file>:<line>: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
<file>:<line>: error: expected ';' before 'int'
<file>:<line>: error: invalid use of qualified-name '::SuccessCode'
```

The piece of code where it happens is as simple as this:

```
class Test
{
  static Status debug_function(void)
  {
    return Status::SuccessCode();   // this would be <file>:<line> mentioned above
    // and this one too:
    // return Status::FailureCode("test");
  }
};
```

And here's the code for Status (*and yes it's properly included, because I would have an error if the include file was invalid*):

```
namespace CODES
{
  enum Values { Success = 0, Failed = 1 };
}

class Status
{
private:
  CODES::Values code;
  string msg;
public:
  Status(CODES::Values val, const string &i_msg ): code(val), msg(i_msg) {}

  static Status SuccessCode(void)
  {
    return Status(CODES::Success, "");
  }

  static Status FailureCode(const string &fail_msg)
  {
    return Status(CODES::Failed, fail_msg);
  }
};
```

So, what is wrong with this piece of code ? And it compiles properly under VC++!

EDIT: Actually, the code for SuccessCode and FailureCode are in a *.cpp file. I put them in the class declaration because the error message is still the same!

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the smallest **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please read http://sscce.org/ for more information.

Comment: The code you posted is fine. The problem is elsewhere. Perhaps you are including an X11 header like `X11/Xwindows.h` which has `#define Status int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a complete program, I'll have to guess. My guess is: you have a `#define Status int` somewhere in your program.

Comment: it was indeed ambiguous... first, I tried to #undef Status, but did not work! So, I rename it in some places, and it solves the problem in those places... so, now I will renamed this in a lot of places, but at least... it works now... thanks buddy!